# Change of location.search does not trigger a rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

In some of my components I have code like this:

```
<Link to="?section=A">TEXT A</Link>
<Link to="?section=B">TEXT B</Link>
<Link to="?section=C">TEXT C</Link>
```

Other components should rerender if the search query changes. For this I wrap these components with the HOC `withRouter`. This seems not to work properly. I would expect a rerender is the expected bahavior? What might be the issue? If `pathname` is changed, everything is working as expected.

I use React 16.8 and React Router 4.